# Trouble autoconnecting to wireless network after automounting USB drive

Tags: wireless, headless, fstab

I'm having issues SSHing into a headless Raspberry Pi over the wireless network. I set up the fresh install properly with `/boot/ssh` and `wpa_supplicant.conf`, and I even modified `etc/network/interface` on first boot to include

`allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

so that it would autoconnect. This works fine until I try to automount a USB drive by mapping the drive's UUID to the mount point usng `fstab`. Only after I do this and reboot (`sudo reboot`) does the wpa_supplicant service fail to execute. I suspect that the `fstab` configuration (`UUID=35E3-026E /media/backup vfat user,auto,fmask=0111,dmask=0000 0 0`) conflicts with the new `/etc/network/interface` configuration somehow, but I am relatively new to working with raspberry pi, and am learning as I go. Any help resolving this issue, i.e. making it possible to connect automatically to the wireless network after configuring a USB interface to automount, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "set up the fresh install properly" and "modified etc/network/interface" are inconsistent - you can do one or the other. This almost certainly has nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: @Milliways can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: You don't say which OS BUT there is no need to modify  etc/network/interface, and this is usually counterproductive. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Milliways thanks for your input but I think I resolved this particular issue after many hours of troubleshooting. Turns out that yanking the power chord without a proper shutdown causes a file system corruption and makes it necessary to reflash the OS - who knew?!! (Yes I realize that this did not necessarily reflect the system I provided but the solution has been found)

Comment: Given the issue is resolved you should delete your question.